# how to iab <CR> temporarily in gVim

Tags: vim

I put this in my `_vimrc`

```
iab fi for(int i=0; i<; i++)<CR>{<CR>}<ESC>2kf<a
```

It expand `fi` to `for...loop`

```
for(int i=0; i< █; i++)
{
}
```

After input `100`, then hit `ENTER`, I want to open a new line between `{...}`

```
for(int i=0; i< 100; i++)
{
    █
}
```

Is there some way to do this?
Thanks!

---

I use a self-destroying mapping to `<CR>`, I think there's another way.

```
iab fi for(int i=0; i<; i++)<CR>{<CR>}<ESC>2kf<a<C-R>=EatSpace()<CR>

fun! EatSpace()
    let nr = getchar()
    call MapEnter()
    if nr==32
        return ''
    else
        return nr2char(nr)
    endif
endfun

fun! MapEnter()
    inoremap <CR> <ESC>:iunmap <C-V><CR><CR>jo
    return ''
endfun
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [snipmate vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) is exactly providing this feature.

`for<Tab>` will produce the following code :

```
 for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
 {
    /* code */
 }
```

On the following `<TAB>` press you'll jump to `count` then `/* code */`

You can also easily customize the snippets of code you want to insert.

If you don't want to use an external plugin you can still download snipmate code to see how it is done.

Comment: vim-snipmate is a fork that implements adictional features to snipmate --> https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate